# How to Add a Blank field in a DropDown List

Tags: sql, drop-down-menu, datasource

I need to add a blank field to a drop-down list which is connected to a database. I tried with the Edit Items but it did not Work.

Code:

Thanks for any help

Comment: Add the blank field to the table? ;-) Can you post the code used link the your DDL to your table/sql?

Comment: Please provide a bit more information than that. Otherwise, this question is likely to be closed soon...

Comment: I dont wish to add a blank field to the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to finally do it I added a list item with a value of -1 and I disabled the view state of the dropdown.

The code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroup" runat="server" DataSourceID="getGroup" 
DataTextField="group_name" DataValueField="group_id" AutoPostBack="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="ddlGroup_SelectedIndexChanged" 
AppendDataBoundItems="True" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
     <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Group</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're doing it in C# and Asp.NET this should do it

```
dropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
dropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
```